# using codeigniter _remap(); with persian characters

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, remap

im using _remap(); in my controller and trying to route the address like this

[http://localhost/courses/سلامتی](http://localhost/courses/%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AA%DB%8C)

but my $course value is =

%D8%B4%D8%B3%D8%B4%D8%B3%D8%B4%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%B4%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%B4%D8%B3%DB%8C

```
    public function _remap($slug) {
        $data['title'] = ucfirst("Blog");
        $data['course'] = $slug;

        parent::setTemplate('views/courses/view', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer
$data['course'] = $slug;
should change to
$data['course'] = rawurldecode ($slug);